# Select file/folder in namespace extension in windows explorer c#/vb .net

Tags: c#, namespaces

I am having a namespace extension implemented, which is visible in "MY Computer". I want to write automated test cases to browse through the same. I am able to open the explorer window till the namespace extension. as -

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "shell:::{CLSID of my namespace }")
```

next I want to search for a particular folder name inside the window opened. For example if i give input as "temp", then my mouse should move to "temp" folder in the namespace explorer window. then I double click on the mouse's current position and enter that folder. next i give input as "doc1.doc", then my mouse should be able to locate & move to "doc1.doc" file. 
Also getDirectory or GetFile etc APIs won't work because I don't have a standard drive associated with my namespace & don't have a relative path either.

Please help.

Comment: It sounds like you're writing your tests to exercise `explorer.exe` rather than writing tests against your code. Why aren't you (trying to) exercise your code programatically?

Comment: Each of my folder name is associated with a unique id (returned from server at runtime & stored in a hash map at client side). So whenever I double click on the folder name, internally that unique id is passed, which I will not be aware of as it can change dynamically. Hence I cannot exercise my code directly here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the browsing part of my namesapce extension by using sendkeys command. I used it to open the explorer window first (Win + E). Next I try simulating the keypress, say if i have to double click a folder called 'temp', I send 'temp' as keystrokes and press 'Enter'. The '[Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)' proved very helpful in achieving the same.

Doing a mouse simulation seemed very tricky and risky, as read from a number of posts, so avoided that.

I did not want to execute my code directly (for that I already have unit tests written), but I wanted to simulate the way user works and that would fire my code internally.